# attachEvent not working in chrome browser for focusout event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have below code working fine in IE 9 but when I am going through Chrome I am getting the error **'element has no method"attachEvent"'**. I tried using.on as well as addEventListener() still I am unable to get through. The element used here is a SharePoint people picker field. I am referring jquery 2.1.

Please advice if I am missing anything?

Code:

```
var element = getPeoplePickerRelControl("User", "div[Title='People Picker']");

    if (element != null) {
        $(element).focusin(function () {
            _cardHolderInfo = getUserDetails(element.innerHTML);
        });
       // if(element.attachEvent)
       element.attachEvent("onfocusout", manipulateLeaderProfile);
```

Comment: Can you add HTML code also

Comment: Or you're looking for `addEventListener('blur')`

Comment: I am not sure how html part is affecting it. can you be specific what you are looking for in innerhtml.   Its too big in size to be copied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attachEvent is specific for IE only. If you want to attch any event in Chrome you should use addEventListener method. Attach events as shown below

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1){
    element.attachEvent("focusout", manipulateLeaderProfile);
}
else{
    element.addEventListener("focusout", manipulateLeaderProfile, false);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Or just let browsers with `attachEvent` die and only support `addEventListener`. That works too :)

Comment: @user2920481 remove "on" from "onfocusout" or replace it with "blur" in order for this snippet to work properly. Event names are supposed to be without "on" inside `addEventListener`.

Comment: Yes, we should remove on from the event name. I was just explaining to use addeventListener method. Thank you for pointing ths out. Updated the code.